# Sort all ids of a table separated by comma in an array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I want to display the ids of  all columns of a table separated by comma in an array

```
$select_client= "SELECT id FROM `table`";
$sql=$dbconn->prepare($select_client);
$sql->execute();
$wlvd=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach($wlvd as $rows);
if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
    foreach($wlvd as $rows){
        $id = $rows->id;
        $array_id= array($id);
        echo  $array_id;
    }
}
```

Result should be like this 1,2,3,4.....

Where 1,2,3,... are ids of tabletable

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by `$id = $rows->id;$array_id= array($id);echo  $array_id;`? Why not simply do `echo $rows->id;`? `order by id`  would sort the ids.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: _Small Note_ There is not much point preparing a query that has no parameters and is only being run once. A simple `->query()` would suffice in this situation

Comment: You can do `$select_client= "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) ids FROM `table`";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the the `$rows->id;` to a variable `$id` which you then add to an array and immediately echo the array (which will be an  Array to string conversion)

You could add to `$array_id[]` on each iteration. After that use [implode](https://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) with a comma to get your desired string:

```
foreach($wlvd as $rows){
    $array_id[] = $rows->id;
}
echo implode(',', $array_id);
```

Comment: Our answers were practically the same :D

Comment: Obviously, there is a better answer that needs to be promoted.

Comment: And the logical conclusion would be to downvote mine?

Comment: Not my down vote, but could it be, because your answer should be a one-liner?

Comment: I meant `implode(',', array_column($wlvd, 'id'));`

Answer (score 2):

If you changed the mode with which you fetch the data you can use simple array functions with the result rather than having to convert it from an object to an array in a loop...

```
$select_client= "SELECT id FROM `table`";
$sql=$dbconn->prepare($select_client);
$sql->execute();
$wlvd=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);    // Changed mode here 
echo implode(",", $wlvd);
```

Although you can with PHP 7+ use `array_column()` with objects.